# How to set additional hosts in default.addnhosts

Tags: libvirt

I have a virtual machine for which `libvirtd` starts a `dnsmasq` server with the additional hosts config file `/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts`. The file seems to be generated, because whenever I add a host to the file and restart `libvirtd`, the file is empty again.

How to add hosts to the file?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the `<dns><host><hostname>` fields in the network XML, `sudo virsh net-dumpxml default`

https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsAddress